# Listviews with Checkboxes in Android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

Can a Listview containing Checkboxes(CheckBox and String label next to the checkbox. The strings are fetched from a string array tab in the strings.xml file) be implemented without a custom adapter?

Comment: search your question on google, you will get a solution. If you have any issue in code then please ask.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be done without using a custom adapter. You can easily use a custom adapter to create custom list views. Why don't you want to use a custom adapter?

Comment: No, no! I was just curious.